# Table already exist sql

Tags: mysql, sql

When trying to import database 
Error
SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_ihrss_plugin` (
  `Ihrss_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Ihrss_path` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Ihrss_link` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `Ihrss_target` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Ihrss_title` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `Ihrss_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Ihrss_status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Ihrss_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Ihrss_extra1` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Ihrss_extra2` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `Ihrss_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> **#1050 - Table 'wp_ihrss_plugin' already exists**

and 5 more tables ; when try to drop one it show that there is another one

Comment: Can you put here the error message that you get when you try to drop a table?

Comment: i already wrote it bro ; coz its too long to put it here as a comment

Comment: It seems that table 'wp_ihrss_plugin' already exists. Try to drop it and recreate after with your SQL DDL.

Comment: I tried to drop it but it happens again and again

Comment: What is the error message that you received when you try to drop it?

Comment: same problem with another table 'temp' 'wp_cn_social_icon' 'wp_commentmeta'

Answer (score 1):

One possible approacj to deal with this would be to drop and recreate the object. For instance:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `foo`;
CREATE TABLE `foo` ( ... );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some duplicate tables present in your database dump.

Check the sql file from which you are trying to import

Comment: I Export it from a live database

Comment: From live database how are you exporting ? are you using any tool or did you write any script ? can you provide more information about that ?

Comment: I just enter to the database and click Export just that

Comment: Im using PhpMyAdmin

Comment: from PhpMyAdmin db to where are you trying to export ?

Comment: to another PhpMyAdmin db

Comment: Check the database schema on db2.. whether it previously has the tables you are trying to export from db1.. If so drop those tables and re-try to export

Comment: YEAH i tried to drop them coz there's 5 or 6 tables with the same problem

Comment: Instead of exporting data and structure try to export data only. if you are trying to export db1 to db2 every time then table gets created every time

Comment: trying that but

Comment: Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25)
SQL query: Edit Edit

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;

MySQL said: Documentation

#2006 - MySQL server has gone away

Comment: which query are you running ? **MySQL server has gone away** this error comes when you are trying to execute a long running query which has been timed out by server